# Flutter Google-Map Markers with zIndex do not work reliably

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I have a map with a collection of markers on them. I need to be able to control the zIndex of the markers.

Without any zIndex code, the map works as expected, each marker is clickable (if it can be seen).

But after adding zIndex information the markers seem to gain a significant invisible wrapper and block access to nearby markers (see picture - it is now hard to click on one of the pink markers).

(I can also replicate this error with Google's example code for the plugin itself.)

```
  Set<Marker> mkMarkers(List<Resto> restos) {
    this.widget._zIndex = restos.length.toDouble();

    return Set.from(
      restos.asMap().map(
        (int idx, Resto r) {
          double hue = (r.qname == this.widget.viewModel.selectedResto)
              ? BitmapDescriptor.hueOrange
              : 319.0;
          return MapEntry(
              idx,
              Marker(
                markerId: MarkerId(r.name),
                position: LatLng(r.lat, r.lng),
                onTap: () => this.widget.viewModel.onSelectResto(r.qname),
                icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(hue),
                // code below does not work as expected
                zIndex: (r.qname == this.widget.viewModel.selectedResto)
                    ? this.widget._zIndex
                    : idx.toDouble(),
              ));
        },
      ).values,
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: What did you use as the marker image?

Comment: the default Google marker

Comment: I would register this as an issue on the plugin repo.